# Where is the code to fetch the 'more views` images?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, magento-community, thumbnail

In magento1.9.2.4 where is the php code to fetch the thumbnail images in `more view` section in product details page?

Answer (score 0):

You can find code for more views thumnail from,

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`

Get all media images from block,

```
$this->getGalleryImages()
```

Block file is **`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media`**.

Thanks.